# Reducing Image height results in cutting Image using object-fit:cover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to decrease Image height without stretching the image. but Its cutting bottom portion of Image.

Tried with **Object cove**r : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZpLoZ

Tried with **container** :    https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzprgx

```css
.cover {    
    object-fit: cover;    
}
```

```html
<img height="260px" width="290px" class="cover"  src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj631.png'>
```

**Original image** :

[image]

Image after reduce height **cut the bottom portion** of image:

[image]

Comment: `object-fit: contain; `

Comment: @Morpheus thanks, but now if i decrease height, automatically width also decreasing as from this https://jsfiddle.net/oma1kxyb/37/ to this https://jsfiddle.net/oma1kxyb/36/

Comment: If height reduce image will be stretch, because images works with aspect ratio.

Comment: what contain does is that it fits the image to the space its given keeping its aspect ratio.

Comment: `ctrl + a` in result you can see it has the same width.

Comment: @LokeshGupta so only i tried `Object cover`

Comment: @stackoverflowuser try `object-fit:fill`

Comment: @LokeshGupta i tried, but image will stretch.....

Comment: Yes because image works with aspect ratio if you reduce height and width as it is it will stretch.

Comment: Then use width, because when you reduce width height will also adjust according to width. i posted working fiddle check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147817/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-lokesh-gupta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```css
.clip {
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsblL.jpg");
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px 230px;
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border:none;
    clip: rect(50px,275px,198px,142px);
    left:-60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIZYv.jpg" width="230"  height="230" />
 <img class="clip" width="150" height="150" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer works with both cases. You don't need to give a fixed width or height to image.

```
.cover {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%; 
}
```

Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgzNRw) updated

Comment: Sorry, this will not work without using `body{
  height: 150px;
}` ,  when i used `body` in site it gave some other issues..... also width will increase if i increase height.....

Comment: @viCky it's not un-necessary. If you give your wraper smaller width than height then image in your codepen is not fitting correctly

Answer (score 0):

**object-fit** can be set with one of these five values:

**fill:** this is the default value which stretches the image to fit the content box, regardless of its aspect-ratio.
contain: increases or decreases the size of the image to fill the box whilst preserving its aspect-ratio.

**cover:** the image will fill the height and width of its box, once again maintaining its aspect ratio but often cropping the image in the process.
none: image will ignore the height and width of the parent and retain its original size.

**scale-down:** the image will compare the difference between none and contain in order to find the smallest concrete object size.
 this is the default value which stretches the image to fit the content box, regardless of its aspect-ratio.

**contain:** increases or decreases the size of the image to fill the box whilst preserving its aspect-ratio.

**cover:** the image will fill the height and width of its box, once again maintaining its aspect ratio but often cropping the image in the process.

**none:** image will ignore the height and width of the parent and retain its original size.

**scale-down:** the image will compare the difference between none and contain in order to find the smallest concrete object size.

So if you use CONTAIN `.cover { object-fit: contain; }`  instead of COVER, you should be fine.

SECONDLY
When you use container, you have given height and width 100%. So the image will take the height and width of the container, no matter what is the aspect ratio of the image. For that you need to make one of the attributes as auto. Either 
`.container img {width: auto; or height:auto;}`

Comment: this solution doesn't work when having fixed container height. And you need both `width:auto;` `height:auto;` not just one of them

Comment: Sorry, this will not work without using `body{
  height: 150px;
}` ,  when i used `body` in site it gave some other issues..... also width will increase if i increase height.....

Comment: please ignore the previous comment and look at the answer above. You do not need to edit the body and just edit either `.cover` or `.container img` as stated in my answer above

Comment: now i tried `.container img {width: auto;` as  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzprgx but still when i increase or decrease height, width also changing according to height.....

Comment: if you want to keep the aspect ratio of your image fixed, the width will change automatically when you change the height. This is pretty obvious. I am not sure why this is a problem.

Comment: @viCky i guess it will create issue in site, let me update your code in site and i will let you know....

Comment: CSS: `#simple1 {
    left: 688px;
    top: 540px;
    /* clip: rect(46px, 187px, 290px, 107px); */
}`
HTML: `<img height="150px" width="150px" class="cover" id="simple1" src="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/y/ty.png">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147818/discussion-between-vicky-and-stackoverflow-user).

Comment: Were you able to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `contain` as mentioned by others. Just posting a code which i came across which might help you. Ref: [LINK](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/myPZwN)

```css
body {
  font-family: Avenir, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}

#plain img {
  width: 45%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2.5%;
}

section h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

code {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 100;
}

section img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #eee;
}

section.contain img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

section.cover img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

section.none img {
  object-fit: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS object-fit</h1>
<section id="plain">
  <h1>original images</h1>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/apex.jpg" alt>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/le-helicron.jpg" alt>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Base style: <code>img { width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid; background: #eee; }</code></h1>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/apex.jpg" alt>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/le-helicron.jpg" alt>
  <h2>Images squished</h2>
</section>

<section class="contain">
  <h1>Base style + <code>img { object-fit: contain }</code></h1>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/apex.jpg" alt>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/le-helicron.jpg" alt>
  <h2>Images letterboxed, correct aspect ratio maintained</h2>
</section>

<section class="cover">
  <h1>Base style + <code>img { object-fit: cover; }</code></h1>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/apex.jpg" alt>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/le-helicron.jpg" alt>
  <h2>Images expand to cover width and height, correct aspect ratio maintained</h2>
</section>

<section class="none">
  <h1>Base style + <code>img { object-fit: none; }</code></h1>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/apex.jpg" alt>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/le-helicron.jpg" alt>
  <h2>Images expand to actual size, cropped inside set width and height, correct aspect ratio maintained</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: can you please update an answer only for issue that i am facing.....  i tried in your code , but i didt got any solution from that code.....

Comment: posted as a reference

Comment: i saw what u trying to do. if you stretch the image it will look ugly. if you fit the image it will contain whitespace. but if you have a exact size as the required size then it will look ok.

Comment: did u try resize the image and then use -margins?

Comment: you could use fill and use -margins but then some of the content will be cropped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147883/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-hash).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height` and use only `width` because if you reduce `height` not `width` image will stretch. (You can play `box` `width` to check it.)

I posted a working fiddle to better understanding.

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
}

img.cover {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img class="cover" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj631.png'>
</div>
```